# In Laravel/Eloquent, how do I include results from model::all() without attributes and relationships in json?

Tags: json, laravel, eloquent

Laravel version: laravel-laravel-936160f

```
$data = entities\org::all();

return var_dump($data);
```

I get data on the all() call, but I only want to emit the column tuples. And, because I can't call toJson() on $data, I have output the result as var_dump instead:

> array(612) {
>
> > [0]=> object(entities\Org)#34 (5) {
> >
> > > ["attributes"]=> array(3) {
> > >
> > > > ["org_id"]=> int(1)
> > > >
> > > > ["name"]=> string(28) "some name"
> > > >
> > > > ["short_name"]=> string(15) "some short name"
> > >
> > > } ["original"]=> array(3) {
> > >
> > > > ["org_id"]=> int(1)
> > > >
> > > > ["name"]=> string(28) "some name"
> > > >
> > > > ["short_name"]=> string(15) "some short name"
> > >
> > > } ["relationships"]=> array(0) { }
> > >
> > > ["exists"]=> bool(true)
> > >
> > > ["includes"]=> array(0) { }
> >
> > }
> >
> > [1]=>...

How can I get basic json tuples out? (org_id,name,shortname). I can iterate the data array, but I was thinking there's gotta be a faster/better way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Laravel 3:

```
$data = entities\org::all();
return Response::eloquent($data);
```

In Laravel 4:

```
return entities\org::all();
```

Both Laravel 3 and Laravel 4 provide automatic methods to return the json representations.

Laravel 3 Resources:

http://laravel.com/docs/database/eloquent#to-array
https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/laravel/helpers.php#L281
https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/laravel/response.php#L136
https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/laravel/database/eloquent/model.php#L589

Laravel 4 Resources:

http://four.laravel.com/docs/eloquent#converting-to-arrays-or-json
https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L1409
https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Support/Collection.php#L200

Hope all that helps.

Comment: Yes. I have seen and read these. However, I do not get json back. Instead, I'm getting an "Array to string conversion" error on the following:

`$data = entities\org::all();`
`return $data;`

Comment: Specific error is as follows:
**Location:**
.../laravel/response.php on line 272

**Stack Trace:**

#0 ...laravel/laravel.php(42): Laravel\Error::native(8, 'Array to string...', '...', 272)
#1 ...laravel/response.php(272): Laravel\{closure}(8, 'Array to string...', '...', 272, Array)
#2 ...laravel/laravel.php(180): Laravel\Response->render()

Comment: Jeesh! I was trying to use L4 syntax. L3 syntax indeed works just fine. Thanks @William.